# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" when doing SQL subquery in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Here is my simplified code (little more than some basic elements to cause the SQL not to execute):

```
select *
from (
    select replace(mytxtfield, "llama", "") as badones 
    from XYZ
)
where badones is not null;
```

The outer query runs fine when the WHERE cause is:

```
 badones like "ZZZ-[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

but it breaks when the WHERE cause includes more than one LIKE (of any digit matching pattern) such as:

```
badones like "ZZZ-[0-9][0-9]" OR 
badones like "ZZZ-[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

More info:

- mytxtfield is of type Text
- It doesn't matter if there is a WHERE cause in the inner query to check eliminate null / empty strings.
- 64-bit office

Comment: What data type is badbones?

Comment: I'm assuming badones would be a string, because REPLACE takes two strings and returns a string ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/replace-function-HA001228898.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

Since your sub-query returns the alias "badnews", you must use it in place of "badones" in your
outer query. The following  produces no errors:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select replace(mytxtfield, "llama", "") as badnews 
    from XYZ
)  
WHERE (((badnews) Like "ZZZ-[0-9][0-9]" Or (badnews) Like "ZZZ-[0-9][0-9][0-9]"));
```

Comment: Sorry, badnews was a typo. I edited my post to correct.

Comment: I'll try this proposed solution, which seems the only difference is the search column in the WHERE cause is surrounded by parenthesis, and report if it fixes the issue. Side note: I tried putting the WHERE cause predicate in parenthesis, as given here, but it has no effect.